# parse.com is there one Installation object per device?

Tags: android, ios, parse-platform

I have an iOS app builded on Parse. I use push notification so I use the Installation table. My problem is that, when I use the same user account on two different devices (two different iPhones), there is still only one Installation entry in the table. My thinking is that there should be one entry per device, as each will have its own token?

Do you know if there should be 1 Installation entry per device **OR** 1 per user account?

Comment: Yes, there is, how are you testing the table?

Comment: @Wain There is 1 entry per device or 1 entry per account?

Comment: Well, I use one device, register for token, then save in Installation. Then I use another device, register for token, then save in Installation. It overwrites the current entry instead of giving me a new entry.

Comment: 1 per device. Each device generates a unique token and that is what the installations relate to.

Answer (score 0):

According to "[Managing Push Subscriptions with Installation Objects](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/managing-device-data-with-installation-objects/)" when a device registers for push notifications via the client SDK, the push service works behind the scenes to manage the device’s subscriptions.

> This subscription you can view and modify through “**Installation**”
>   objects, each of which corresponds to an installation of your app on a
>   device.

Installation objects are automatically created and modified when SDK push methods like **subscribeToChannel** and **unsubscribeFromChannel** are called, and are fetched by the getSubscribedChannels SDK method.

I would also want to comment that looking at my own tables on Parse I have a new row in **Installation table** for every new version (appVersion) of my app

Answer (score 0):

[See this link](https://www.parse.com/questions/best-way-to-save-unique-iphone-installations) for an explanation of how the `Installation` class works by Héctor Ramos from the Parse team.

This gist of it is:

> The Installation class contains objects that are just that - unique
>   installations of your app. When you delete the app from the phone,
>   then reinstall it, this corresponds to a new installation. If the app
>   is restored from iCloud, though, the same Installation object will be
>   used.
>
> You will probably want to track IAP data in the User object instead,
>   then link users to their installations. A user can have more than one
>   installation, if they install the app on an iPhone and iPad, or if
>   your app is available for Android, too.